# Swift infinite background not aligning to left side

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is the code that I use to make the 'infinite' background by creating a new image each time and then replacing the old one constantly. However, at the start of the app, only half of the image is visible. I want the image to be aligned to the left side of the screen when starting, instead of at the centre.

*This app is in landscape orientation*

```
 let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "thebackground")
 let movebg = SKAction.moveBy(x: -bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 25)
 let replacebg = SKAction.moveBy(x: bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0) //jumps the bg to original position
 let movebgForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([movebg, replacebg]))

        background.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width/2, y: self.frame.midY)

        for var i in 0 ..< 3 {

                var loop:CGFloat = CGFloat (i) * bgTexture.size().width

                background = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
                background.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width/2 + loop, y: self.frame.midY)
                background.size.height = self.frame.height
                background.zPosition = -2
                background.run(movebgForever)


                self.addChild(background)
            }
```

Comment: If I were you, I would not run multiple actions, instead attach all of your background nodes to a parent SKNode, then just put an action on the parent node

Answer (score 3):

I think your starting position is wrong and the line should be the following. The x position needs to be negative to align with the left edge.

```
background.position = CGPoint(x: -bgTexture.size().width/2 + loop, y: self.frame.midY)
```

Comment: It works just the way I wanted it to, thank you very much! @GaryMakin

Comment: @user7594231 You should consider accepting this answer if it helped you with your issue. To accept the answer, click the check-mark. This is not an obligation, but it helps the community because it indicates that answer has solved the actual issue.